# FluentValidation date formatting not respecting culture in ASP.NET webapi

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization, webapi, fluentvalidation

I've configured at Startup.cs of my ASP.NET webapi the Culture for FluentValidation like below:

`ValidatorOptions.Global.LanguageManager.Culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");`

The messages are follow the selected culture.
When I'm running the tests in my local machine, the message is like expeted:

> "'Data Aniversario' deve ser superior a '31/01/2022 00:00:00'."

But when the same test run on CI pipeline the message do not use the same datetime format:

> "'Data Aniversario' deve ser superior a '01/31/2022 00:00:00'."

The rule used for the field:

`RuleFor(x => x.DataAniversario).NotEmpty().GreaterThan(x => x.MenorDataPermitida);`

Answer (score 0):

To solve it was necessary to configure the default thread current culture in Startup.cs too:

`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");`